# Vim - producing a drop down menu for manual search

Tags: vim

I am trying to write my own autocomplete function in Vim which mimics a nice feature of the `CTRL-x CTRL-(l,n, or p)` autocomplete, namely I want to produce a drop down menu of possible choices to select from.

My issue with the commands above is that they search to complete the current word and I would like to create a search that handles any sequence of consecutive special characters as well.  I have worked out the search feature for my function using regular expressions and the `normal` command, but I do now know how to produce the menu of choices.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

(Note: I know there are plugins that may offer this feature, but I am more interested in understanding how to accomplish this using the built-in Vim functionality.)

Comment: Please explain what you want more precisely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 5):

I believe this example from the documentation of `complete()` does exactly what you are asking to do.  Copied here from `:help complete(`:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=ListMonths()<CR>

func! ListMonths()
    call complete(col('.'), ['January', 'February', 'March',
        \ 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
        \ 'October', 'November', 'December'])
    return ''
endfunc
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  I will try it out and post the code once I get the bugs worked out.